# API documentation and limitation for NFC tags on Android

Tags: android, api, sdk, nfc

I'm new at NFC and I'm trying to look up documentation what is possible and what is not but I have a hard time finding the right ressources.
I'm therefore looking for guidance pointing towards the right ressources.

The problem I have is a lot of the ressources I find require a third party app. E.g. [Trigger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher). With Trigger you could implement more complex logic (e.g. check time, if time falls within a certain range, start google maps pointing to work address, always start Spotify) but it'd only work if you have Trigger installed.
I however am looking for a NFC project that works without requiring installing an extra app. **Things that work on any Android device with latest OS are for example**:

- toggling Bluetooth
- connect to WLAN with SSID and password
- open an URL
- ...

I've seen it's possible to write an NFC tag to pair with a Bluetooth device. However when using a different phone, that does not have the NFC writer app installed, will the NFC tag still work? [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4FdXO1nnJQ)
My NFC tags are still shipping so I can't test. Also I prefer reading documentation and implementing according to docs over trial and error.
Newer Bluetooth speakers have NFC. I'm unsure if you can turn NFC-dumb devices into NFC-smart devices. (The NFC-smart devices may be telling the bluetooth speaker to go into pairing mode which is something you cannot do when you create a NFC tag.)

I've been trying to look up documentation what's supported by default but I have a hard time finding these ressources.

For now I want to focus my attention to Android only since I do not own Apple devices. I am aware what may work on Android may not work on Apple.

**I'm looking for the API method calls documentation for Android that shows above mentioned bullets points being possible.**

What is possible? What are the limitations?

Answer (score 0):

The API for NFC is well documented. You will find that on the android developer site ([Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc)).

However, what is supposed to happen once you read a NFC tag is a different story. Your examples have nothing to do with NFC, even so they appear possible. This is what you have to cover with your app.

Comment: I'm trying to find the documentation what is possible with a NFC tag **without** taking the extra step of installing an app. For instance I can write NFC tag to open a custom URL and with any other Android phone I can open the URL without using an extra app. Same with establishing a connection with a WLAN using a certain SSID and password. **What is possible by default with the latest Android OS version**. I am aware you can do anything if you develop your own app (or using a third party app).

Comment: The question formulated differently would be: Documentation of the default installed NFC ready apps on latest Android OS. Which apps are NFC ready and what can they do? E.g. the settings, browser and contacts app act upon NFC tags. Where is this documented? Are there other apps? I need to see the API in order to know its limitations as well as how I can write my own NFC tags in compliance without relying on third party apps.

Answer (score 0):

You are not after the API documentation on Android which is well documented at the low level but poorly documented as a System.

What you are after is the NFC Forum specification and what level of support that your particular version of Android natively supports these specification.

Unfortunately the NFC Forum specification are mostly a paid for resource can cover things like how to write an NDEF message for Bluetooth pairing, Wifi setup, etc.
Though some of these specification can be found hidden on the internet or you can pay to become an NFC Forum member.

You can get an idea of what Android OS natively supports by looking at the source code of the System App that handles this.

(mostly in ) https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/nfc/NfcDispatcher.java

But additional support for other message types can be added by any other App include apps installed by OEM vendors like Samsung, etc